# Fundamental Networking Understanding

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, networking

treading some unfamiliar waters. I'm currently writing a game client in Unity/C# and a game server in NodeJS. I've been doing a lot of Googling to try and get some answers, but there are some fundamentals I'm definitely not understanding. From what I understand, there are three relevant IP addresses here: my external IP address, 127.0.0.1, and 0.0.0.0. I've tried every permutation of these for client and server (with or without common sense), and the only combination that works is 127.0.0.1 x 127.0.0.1. I assume ultimately that the server will need to be on 0.0.0.0, but currently Unity errors out because the socket is already in use by the server- I assume that this would not be an issue with remote hosting.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to host this on my home computer without socket overlap? Virtual machine?
2. Why does 127.0.0.1 x 127.0.0.1 work? Does the client convert it to another local address under the hood? I assume that they would both be UDP/127.0.0.1/port sockets.

I'd like to put the multiplayer into this game as soon as possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible, with virtual hosts, virtual machines. If you are working in windows, take a look at XAMPP or WAMPP if you are in a Mac.
2. This is a little big larger:

127.0.0.1 is the localhost (basically, yourself) also known as loopback adress.

And 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-adress. Basically it serves to designate invalid targets, it's like a placeholder for "unknown" adresses. Serves to designate invalid targets doesn't means that is an invalid adress!

In your context, if you're using the 0.0.0.0 as a server it means "all IPv4 adresses on the local machine". If a host has two IP addresses, 192.168.1.1 and 10.1.2.1, and a server running on the host listens on 0.0.0.0, it will be reachable at both of those IPs.

This tutorial from Tom Weiland really helps me to learn about on-line programming in Unity, check it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh8XaC0Y5MA